# Torrent with Laravel using Laratracker

Tags: php, laravel

I am implementing the [laratracker](https://github.com/Comforse/laratracker) , a bittorrent tracker built in laravel, but unable to start the download. Only one peer appears to be seeding, Sometimes it is saying "Connecting to peers" and remains at it is.  The code which i am using is :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Announce;

use App\Helpers\BencodeHelper;
use App\Models\Peer;
use App\Models\PeerTorrent;
use App\Models\Torrent;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class AnnounceController extends Controller
{
    const __INTERVAL = 1000;
    const __TIMEOUT = 120;
    const __INTERVAL_MIN = 60;
    const __MAX_PPR = 20;

    public function announce(Request $request)
    {
        Log::info($request->fullUrl());
        $status = 200;
        $content = "";
        $passkey = Input::get('passkey');
        $peer_id = Input::get('peer_id');
        $port = Input::get('port');
        $info_hash = Input::get('info_hash');
        $downloaded = Input::get('uploaded') ? intval(Input::get('uploaded')) : 0;
        $uploaded = Input::get('uploaded') ? intval(Input::get('uploaded')) : 0;
        $left = Input::get('left') ? intval(Input::get('left')) : 0;
        $compact = Input::get('compact') ? intval(Input::get('compact')) : 0;
        $no_peer_id = Input::get('no_peer_id') ? intval(Input::get('no_peer_id')) : 0;

        $ipAddress = '';
        // Check for X-Forwarded-For headers and use those if found
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) && ('' !== trim($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))) {
            $ipAddress = (trim($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']));
        } else {
            if (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) && ('' !== trim($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))) {
                $ipAddress = (trim($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
            }
        }

        $port = $_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'];
        /*if(!$port || !ctype_digit($port) || intval($port) < 1 || intval($port) > 65535)
        {
            $content = BencodeHelper::track("Invalid client port.");
            $status = 401;
            return (new Response(AnnounceController::track($content), $status))
                ->header('Content-Type', $value);
        }

        if ($port == 999 && substr($peer_id, 0, 10) == '-TO0001-XX') {
            die("d8:completei0e10:incompletei0e8:intervali600e12:min intervali60e5:peersld2:ip12:72.14.194.184:port3:999ed2:ip11:72.14.194.14:port3:999ed2:ip12:72.14.194.654:port3:999eee");
        }*/


        if (!$passkey) {
            $content = BencodeHelper::track("Missing passkey.");
            $status = 401;
            return (new Response(AnnounceController::track($content), $status))
                ->header('Content-Type', $value);
        }


        $torrent = Torrent::getByInfoHash(sha1($info_hash));
        if (!$torrent || $torrent == null) {
            $content = "Torrent not registered with this tracker.";
            $status = 404;
            return (new Response(AnnounceController::track($content), $status))
                ->header('Content-Type', $value);
        }

        $user = User::has('passkeys', '=', $passkey)->get();

        if ($user == null) {
            $content = BencodeHelper::track("Invalid passkey.");
            $status = 401;
            return (new Response(AnnounceController::track($content), $status))
                ->header('Content-Type', $value);
        }

        $peer = Peer::getByHashAndPasskey(bin2hex($peer_id), $passkey);

        if ($peer == null) {
            $peer = Peer::create([
                'hash' => bin2hex($peer_id),
                'user_agent' => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
                'ip_address' => $ipAddress,
                'passkey' => $passkey,
                'port' => $port
            ]);
        }

        if (!$info_hash || strlen($info_hash) != 20) {
            $content = BencodeHelper::track("Invalid info_hash.");
            $status = 401;
            return (new Response(AnnounceController::track($content), $status))
                ->header('Content-Type', $value);
        }


        $peer_torrent = PeerTorrent::getByPeerAndTorrent($peer, $torrent);

        if ($peer_torrent == null) {
            $peer_torrent = PeerTorrent::create([
                'peer_id' => $peer->id,
                'torrent_id' => $torrent->id,
                'uploaded' => $uploaded,
                'downloaded' => $downloaded,
                'left' => $left,
                'stopped' => false
            ]);

        } else {
            $peer_torrent->uploaded = $uploaded;
            $peer_torrent->downloaded = $downloaded;
            $peer_torrent->left = $left;
            $peer_torrent->save();
        }

        $seeders = $torrent->getSeedersCount();
        $leechers = $torrent->getLeechersCount();
        $resp = "";
        if ($compact != 1) {
            $resp = "d" . $this->benc_str("interval") . "i" . AnnounceController::__INTERVAL . "e" . $this->benc_str("peers") . "l";
        } else {
            $resp = "d" . $this->benc_str("interval") . "i" . AnnounceController::__INTERVAL . "e" . $this->benc_str("min interval") . "i" . 300 . "e5:" . "peers";
        }

        $peer = array();

        $peer_num = 0;
        foreach ($torrent->getPeersArray() as $row) {
            if ($compact != 1) {
                if ($row["peer_id"] === $peer->hash) {
                    continue;
                }

                $resp .= "d" . $this->benc_str("ip") . $this->benc_str($row['ip']);

                if ($no_peer_id == 0) {
                    $resp .= $this->benc_str("peer id") . $this->benc_str($row["peer_id"]);
                }

                $resp .= $this->benc_str("port") . "i" . $row["port"] . "e" . "e";

            } else {
                $peer_ip = explode('.', $row["ip"]);
                $peer_ip = pack("C*", $peer_ip[0], $peer_ip[1], $peer_ip[2], $peer_ip[3]);
                $peer_port = pack("n*", (int)$row["port"]);
                $time = intval((time() % 7680) / 60);

                if ($left == 0) {
                    $time += 128;
                }

                $time = pack("C", $time);
                $peer[] = $time . $peer_ip . $peer_port;
                $peer_num++;
            }
        }

        if ($compact != 1) {
            $resp .= "ee";
        } else {
            $o = "";
            for ($i = 0; $i < $peer_num; $i++) {
                $o .= substr($peer[$i], 1, 6);
            }
            $resp .= strlen($o) . ':' . $o . 'e';
        }

        $this->benc_resp_raw($resp);
    }

    public function benc_resp($d)
    {
        return $this->benc_resp_raw($this->benc(array('type' => 'dictionary', 'value' => $d)));
    }

    public function benc_resp_raw($x)
    {
        header("Content-Type: text/plain");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");

        if ($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'] == 'gzip') {
            header("Content-Encoding: gzip");
            echo gzencode($x, 9, FORCE_GZIP);
        } else {
            echo $x;
        }
    }

    function benc($obj)
    {
        if (!is_array($obj) || !isset($obj["type"]) || !isset($obj["value"]))
            return;
        $c = $obj["value"];
        switch ($obj["type"]) {
            case "string":
                return $this->benc_str($c);
            case "integer":
                return $this->benc_int($c);
            case "list":
                return $this->benc_list($c);
            case "dictionary":
                return $this->benc_dict($c);
            default:
                return;
        }
    }

    public function benc_str($s)
    {
        return strlen($s) . ":$s";
    }

    public function benc_int($i)
    {
        return "i" . $i . "e";
    }

    public function benc_list($a)
    {
        $s = "l";
        foreach ($a as $e) {
            $s .= $this->benc($e);
        }
        $s .= "e";
        return $s;
    }

    public function benc_dict($d)
    {
        $s = "d";
        $keys = array_keys($d);
        sort($keys);
        foreach ($keys as $k) {
            $v = $d[$k];
            $s .= $this->benc_str($k);
            $s .= $this->benc($v);
        }
        $s .= "e";
        return $s;
    }


    public function hex2bin($hex)
    {
        $r = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($hex); $i += 2) {
            $r .= chr(hexdec($hex{$i} . $hex{($i + 1)}));
        }
        return $r;
    }
}
<?php
```

Not sure what to add or modify to the code to get it working . Help appreciated for the solution .